# How to get rid of attempt to apply specific commit merge

Tags: git

This is driving me absolutely crazy.

I just want to continue on and stop getting this message about **55aaad5**.  **I don't care about it** and I and I want to ignore it or have it go away! I just want to continue rebasing like I have been with `git rebase develop` from my log-in branch I have checked out that's synced with the remote origin/log-in branch.

Every time I try to get past this it keeps making me merge files that I've already resolved in the past!

branches/homepage log-in ✔                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0m
**▶ git status**

```
On branch log-in
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/log-in'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

branches/homepage  log-in ✔                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0m
**▶ git rebase -i develop**

```
error: could not apply 51fcda4... problem with call to API - getting 403

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 51fcda43833973b36fd496c47ab9bcaa0b888a89... problem with call to API - getting 403
```

branches/homepage  a07cc17 ✗                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               14h10m § ✚  ⍉

**▶ git rebase --skip**

```
error: could not apply 55aaad5... added integration test script to package.json

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 55aaad5b7dd394134f238c70b7edd0db8723de23... added integration test script to package.json
```

I'm also trying to get out of this branch and just go back to my original log-in branch but I get

branches/homepage  a07cc17 ✗                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   14h10m  ⍉
**▶ git rebase -i develop**

It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
        git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
        rm -fr "homepage/.git/rebase-merge"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.

branches/homepage  a07cc17 ✗                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   14h19m  ⍉
**▶ git checkout log-in**
src/test/integration/api.integration.spec.js: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first

It forces me to do a git add which then forces me to re-merge a bunch of crap that's already resolved.  How do I say no, I don't want to, just let me check out the log-in branch again?

Ok I did a **git checkout -f log-in**, now I get:

**▶ git status**
On branch log-in
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/log-in'.
Last commands done (55 commands done):
   pick 51fcda4 problem with call to API - getting 403
   pick 55aaad5 added integration test script to package.json
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (5 remaining commands):
   pick d809245 fixed login test
   pick 1edb9a9 cleanup
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'log-in' on 'bbea7dc'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

I am not sure really what state I'm in, I'm not a guru at git.

[image]

Comment: You want to rebase on top of develop, but ignore 55aaad5?

Comment: @C-Otto correct

Comment: In `git rebase -i develop` just delete the line starting with `55aaad5`.

Comment: ok I'll give that a try, thx

Comment: do you know how to tell it to stop forcing me to merge stuff when I'm currently checked out to 55aaad5 when I try to checkout log-in again?

Comment: looks like git checkout -f log-in does it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have a super strong grasp of what's happening when you rebase. I'd highly recommend doing a bit of reading about git. Hitting a problem over the head with the `-f` flag is not a sound solution. 
To give you a little more info on those errors:
When you rebase you are *replaying* past commits *on top of* what you are rebasing on. That is why you are having to deal with files and commits that you have already dealt with. It is possible for commits that you are replaying to have conflicts with what you are rebasing on. An example of an conflict might be: you are rebasing on `develop`, `develop` includes a commit that changes lines 10-15 of `fileA.txt`, and you are replaying a commit that also changes lines 10-15 of `fileA.txt`.
If you are *in the middle* of a rebase (as you would be if you encountered an error while rebasing, and did not fix the error and continue to rebase to completion), then you will be "behind" where you were when you started rebasing. That is because you haven't replayed all of your commits yet. What you can do in that case (as is laid out in the git error message) is to fix the conflict and continue rebasing *or* abort the rebase. If you truly want/need to rebase, then you should do some reading on how to fix a git conflict and, if you can't figure it out, make another SO post. If you just want to completely abort the rebase, and get back to where you were before you started rebasing, then just `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: yea I tried all that, fixing, committing, and it merges but then when I tried to rebase after that, an old change that had already been merged a while back kept resurfacing